# Wordpress: query mySQL or use WP_query

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, wordpress

I built an android app which actually retrieve my blog post from some custom feed in XML format. 
The data in my blog will increase in the next future so i need to change the way of retrieving data.

I decided to build a PHP webservice to query my posts and answer back to the app the necessary data (as JSON encoded data).

There are two different way to build the webservice: build a direct query to the MySQL database or build a query using the php the_content, php the_title, etc  functions (WP_query).
It looks like that querying the My SQL database is more flexible but more complicated.

Which is the best solution between the ones above?

Thanks for your support

Comment: Have you considered the [XMLRPC API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API)?

Comment: No, i didn't considered it. Can you kindly suggest an example? Which is the pro of using this instead of the other solutions?

Comment: The question generated a good answer with the correct argument to support it: WP_QUERY is the right choice to keep the future compatibility between the app and the wordpress blog. I disagree with the closing of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use the `wp_query` because the database may evolve with future Wordpress updates. This means you would have to adapt your mysql query but not you `wp_query` because the change in the mysql database will have been done by the wordpress update itself.

Furthermore you can have a lot of customization using the `wp_query` and it's more likely you don't even need to reach the database directly.

Comment: Thank you. Good consideration. Is it a common way to proceed for developing communication between Wordpress and Android app?

Comment: As long as you are building a webservice and returning a well formatted json You can use it from any other apps! android, ios, windows phone, desktop etc ...